# SOQL Conditional Counting?

Tags: soql, count

I am trying to run a query that will return counts of the different Opportunity Record Types for each user during a particular month.  My query currently looks like this:

> SELECT Owner.Name, COUNT(RecordType.Name)
>   FROM Opportunity
>   WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 1 AND CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR
>   GROUP BY Owner.Name

This gets me the count of all opportunities for each person, but how can I break it down to the individual record types?  FWIW, there are 5 record types, and for the purpose of this report, I only need 3 of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the GROUP BY ROLLUP key phrase to get the number of opportunities by owner and by record type, with extra summary and grand total rows.

```
SELECT Owner.Name,  RecordType.Name, COUNT(Id)
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 1 AND 
    CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR AND
    RecordType.Name IN ('Record Type A','Record Type B','Record Type C')
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Owner.Name, RecordType.Name)
```

This would have output like this:

```
John Doe    Record Type A     3
John Doe    Record Type B     2
John Doe    <<null>>          5
Jane Doe    Record Type A     4
Jane Doe    Record Type B     5
Jane Doe    <<null>>          9
<<null>>    <<null>>         14
```

Where the null rows indicate a subtotal, much like you'd see in a report on the reports tab. If you don't care for the summary rows, you can skip that and use `GROUP BY Owner.Name, RecordType.Name` instead.

Answer (score 3):

you could group the results by ReportType.Name in your query, the query would then look like:

```
SELECT Owner.Name, COUNT(Id), RecordType.DeveloperName 
   FROM Opportunity WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 1 AND CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR 
   GROUP BY Owner.Name, RecordType.DeveloperName
```

This query would then give you the Count of Opportunities per person per record type filtered to the month specified.